# Problems when try to remove KDE Plasma from ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, kde

I have some problems when I try to remove KDE Plasma from Ubuntu 14.04.

I installed KDE Plasma using this command

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

After doing some changes in KDE desktop it was getting a worst and when i switched back to Unity everything was messed up including window colours, shadows, menu appearance, font rendering system and pretty much everything.

Back then i tried to remove it using this command

```
sudo aptitude remove kde-desktop
```

this,

```
sudo apt-get remove kde-full
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
```

and this

```
sudo apt-get remove akonadi-backend-mysql akonadi-server akregator amarok amarok-common amarok-utils apport-kde apturl-kde ark bluedevil cdparanoia cdrdao cryptsetup docbook-xml docbook-xsl dolphin dragonplayer freespacenotifier gnupg-agent gnupg2 gpgsm gpsd gstreamer0.10-qapt gtk2-engines-oxygen gtk3-engines-oxygen gwenview ibus-qt4 icoutils jockey-kde k3b k3b-data kaccessible kaddressbook kamera kate kate-data katepart kcalc kde-baseapps-bin kde-baseapps-data kde-config-gtk kde-config-touchpad kde-runtime kde-runtime-data kde-style-oxygen kde-wallpapers-default kde-window-manager kde-window-manager-common kde-workspace kde-workspace-bin kde-workspace-data kde-workspace-kgreet-plugins kde-zeroconf kdegames-card-data kdegraphics-strigi-analyzer kdelibs-bin kdelibs5-data kdelibs5-plugins kdemultimedia-kio-plugins kdenetwork-filesharing kdepasswd kdepim-kresources kdepim-runtime kdepim-strigi-plugins kdepimlibs-kio-plugins kdesudo kdm kdoctools khelpcenter4 kinfocenter klipper kmag kmail kmenuedit kmix kmousetool knotes konsole kontact kopete kopete-message-indicator korganizer kpat kppp ksnapshot ksysguard ksysguardd ksystemlog ktimetracker ktorrent ktorrent-data kubuntu-debug-installer kubuntu-default-settings kubuntu-desktop kubuntu-docs kubuntu-firefox-installer kubuntu-netbook-default-settings kubuntu-notification-helper kubuntu-web-shortcuts kvkbd kwalletmanager language-selector-kde libakonadi-calendar4 libakonadi-contact4 libakonadi-kabc4 libakonadi-kcal4 libakonadi-kde4 libakonadi-kmime4 libakonadi-notes4 libakonadiprotocolinternals1 libassuan0 libattica0.3 libbluedevil1 libboost-program-options1.46.1 libcalendarsupport4 libcln6 libclucene0ldbl libdebconf-kde0 libdlrestrictions1 libdmtx0a libencode-locale-perl libepub0 libeventviews4 libfile-listing-perl libflac++6 libfont-afm-perl libgadu3 libgif4 libgpgme++2 libgps20 libgrantlee-core0 libhtml-form-perl libhtml-format-perl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-tree-perl libhttp-cookies-perl libhttp-daemon-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl libhttp-negotiate-perl libibus-qt1 libilmbase6 libincidenceeditorsng4 libindicate-qt1 libio-socket-inet6-perl libio-socket-ssl-perl libk3b6 libkabc4 libkactivities-bin libkactivities6 libkalarmcal2 libkateinterfaces4 libkatepartinterfaces4 libkblog4 libkcal4 libkcalcore4 libkcalutils4 libkcddb4 libkcmutils4 libkde3support4 libkdeclarative5 libkdecorations4 libkdecore5 libkdegames5a libkdepim4 libkdepimdbusinterfaces4 libkdesu5 libkdeui5 libkdewebkit5 libkdgantt2 libkdnssd4 libkemoticons4 libkephal4abi1 libkexiv2-10 libkexiv2-data libkfile4 libkholidays4 libkhtml5 libkidletime4 libkimap4 libkio5 libkipi-data libkipi8 libkjsapi4 libkjsembed4 libkldap4 libkleo4 libkmanagesieve4 libkmbox4 libkmediaplayer4 libkmime4 libknewstuff2-4 libknewstuff3-4 libknotifyconfig4 libkntlm4 libkonq-common libkonq5-templates libkonq5abi1 libkontactinterface4 libkopete4 libkparts4 libkpgp4 libkpimidentities4 libkpimtextedit4 libkpimutils4 libkprintutils4 libkpty4 libkresources4 libkrosscore4 libksba8 libkscreensaver5 libksgrd4 libksieve4 libksieveui4 libksignalplotter4 libktexteditor4 libktnef4 libktorrent-l10n libktorrent3 libkunitconversion4 libkwineffects1abi3 libkwinglutils1 libkwinnvidiahack4 libkworkspace4abi1 libkxmlrpcclient4 liblastfm0 libloudmouth1-0 liblwp-mediatypes-perl liblwp-protocol-https-perl libmailcommon4 libmailtools-perl libmailtransport4 libmessagecomposer4 libmessagecore4 libmessagelist4 libmessageviewer4 libmicroblog4 libmpcdec6 libmsn0.3 libmuonprivate1 libmygpo-qt1 libmysqlclient18 libnepomuk4 libnepomukdatamanagement4 libnepomukquery4a libnepomuksync4 libnepomukutils4 libnet-http-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libntrack-qt4-1 libntrack0 libokularcore1abi1 libopenexr6 libotr2 libphonon4 libplasma-geolocation-interface4 libplasma3 libplasmaclock4abi3 libplasmagenericshell4 libpolkit-qt-1-1 libpoppler-qt4-3 libprison0 libprocesscore4abi1 libprocessui4a libqalculate5 libqapt-runtime libqapt1 libqca2 libqca2-plugin-ossl libqgpgme1 libqimageblitz4 libqjson0 libqrencode3 libqt4-designer libqt4-help libqt4-qt3support libqt4-scripttools libqt4-sql-mysql libqt4-test libqtassistantclient4 libqtglib-2.0-0 libqtgstreamer-0.10-0 libqtscript4-core libqtscript4-gui libqtscript4-network libqtscript4-sql libqtscript4-uitools libqtscript4-xml libqtwebkit4 libreoffice-kde libreoffice-style-oxygen libsocket6-perl libsolid4 libsolidcontrol4abi2 libsolidcontrolifaces4abi2 libsoprano4 libstreamanalyzer0 libstreams0 libsyndication4 libtag-extras1 libtaskmanager4abi3 libtemplateparser4 libthreadweaver4 libtimedate-perl liburi-perl libvirtodbc0 libweather-ion6 libwww-perl libwww-robotrules-perl libxml2-utils libxss1 libzip2 muon muon-installer muon-notifier muon-updater mysql-client-core-5.5 mysql-common mysql-server-core-5.5 ntrack-module-libnl-0 odbcinst odbcinst1debian2 okular okular-extra-backends oxygen-cursor-theme oxygen-icon-theme partitionmanager phonon phonon-backend-gstreamer pinentry-gtk2 pinentry-qt4 plasma-dataengines-addons plasma-dataengines-workspace plasma-desktop plasma-netbook plasma-scriptengine-javascript plasma-scriptengine-python plasma-widget-facebook plasma-widget-folderview plasma-widget-kimpanel plasma-widget-menubar plasma-widget-message-indicator plasma-widget-networkmanagement plasma-widgets-addons plasma-widgets-workspace plymouth-theme-kubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-kubuntu-text polkit-kde-1 printer-applet python-kde4 python-pyudev python-qt4 python-qt4-dbus python-sip qapt-batch qapt-deb-installer quassel quassel-data rekonq sgml-data shared-desktop-ontologies software-properties-kde soprano-daemon system-config-printer-kde systemsettings tasks-icons update-manager-kde usb-creator-kde userconfig virtuoso-minimal virtuoso-opensource-6.1-bin virtuoso-opensource-6.1-common xsettings-kde && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

but nothing worked, everything ended up with a error like this

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'ubuntu-drivers-common' instead of 'jockey-kde'
Package 'kde-config-touchpad' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'kubuntu-firefox-installer' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libkdgantt2' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libmuonprivate1' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'system-config-printer-kde' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'tasks-icons' is not installed, so not removed
E: Unable to locate package kde-config-gtk
E: Unable to locate package kdepim-strigi-plugins
E: Unable to locate package kvkbd
E: Unable to locate package language-selector-kde
E: Unable to locate package libattica0.3
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libattica0.3'
E: Unable to locate package libboost-program-options1.46.1
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libboost-program-options1.46.1'
E: Unable to locate package libclucene0ldbl
E: Unable to locate package libkdecorations4
E: Unable to locate package libkdegames5a
E: Unable to locate package libkexiv2-10
E: Unable to locate package libkipi8
E: Unable to locate package libktorrent3
E: Unable to locate package libkwineffects1abi3
E: Unable to locate package libkwinglutils1
E: Unable to locate package libkwinnvidiahack4
E: Unable to locate package libkworkspace4abi1
E: Unable to locate package liblastfm0
E: Unable to locate package libnepomukdatamanagement4
E: Unable to locate package libnepomuksync4
E: Unable to locate package libokularcore1abi1
E: Unable to locate package libotr2
E: Unable to locate package libplasmaclock4abi3
E: Unable to locate package libpoppler-qt4-3
E: Unable to locate package libqapt-runtime
E: Unable to locate package libqapt1
E: Unable to locate package libsolidcontrol4abi2
E: Unable to locate package libsolidcontrolifaces4abi2
E: Unable to locate package libtaskmanager4abi3
E: Unable to locate package printer-applet
E: Unable to locate package userconfig
```

Is there any way that works fine on removing KDE desktop! Please be kind enough to help.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
sudo apt-get purge kubuntu-desktop plasma-desktop
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop -y
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this code solved it for me:

```
apt-get remove kdelibs-bin kdelibs5-data
```

I found this solution in [Debian User Forums](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=102884).